# What does "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weight') at l.start (d3.v3.min.js:4:22672) at GraphTesting:102:5" mean?

Tags: asp.net-core, data-structures, graph, compiler-errors, razor-pages

I have been trying to dynamically populate an undirected graph by making use of matrices. I am using ASP.NET Razor Pages and in the view, I am using JavaScript to plot the graph and in the PageModel I am using C# code to generate the data and pass it to a JSON string. Now, I always get this error that the weight is undefined and I don't know where this weight is coming from because I have not declared any property or variable as weight.

I will leave here all the code that I have tried so far.

This is the Node class:

```
    public class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public Node(int id, string label)
        {
            Id = id;
            Label = label;
        }
    }
```

This is the Link class:

```
    public class Link
    {
        public int Source { get; set; }
        public int Target { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        

        public Link(int source, int target, int value)
        {
            Source = source;
            Target = target;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

This is the PageModel:

```
public class GraphTestingModel : PageModel
    {
        public string GraphData { get; private set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Assuming you have a list of nodes and links
            var nodes = GetNodes();
            var links = GetLinks();

            // Create a data object to hold the nodes and links
            var data = new
            {
                nodes,
                links
            };

            // Serialize the data object to JSON
            GraphData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }

        private List<Node> GetNodes()
        {
            // Create and populate the list of nodes
            var nodes = new List<Node>
            {
                new Node(0, "Myriel"),
                new Node(1, "Napoleon"),
                new Node(2, "MlleBaptistine"),
                new Node(3, "MmeMagloire"),
                new Node(4, "CountessDeLo"),
                new Node(5, "Geborand"),
                new Node(6, "Champtercier"),
                new Node(7, "Cravatte"),
                new Node(8, "Count"),
                new Node(9, "OldMan"),
                new Node(10, "Labarre")
            };

            return nodes;
        }

        private List<Link> GetLinks()
        {
            // Create and populate the list of links
            var links = new List<Link>
            {
                new Link(1, 0, 1),
                new Link(2, 0, 8),
                new Link(3, 0, 10),
                new Link(3, 2, 6),
                new Link(4, 0, 1),
                new Link(5, 0, 1),
                new Link(6, 0, 1),
                new Link(7, 0, 1),
                new Link(8, 0, 2),
                new Link(9, 0, 1)
            };

            return links;
        }
    }
```

And this is the view of the page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spider Diagram</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        svg {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-opacity: 0.6;
        }

        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node text {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph"></div>

    <script>
        var data = @Html.Raw(Model.GraphData);
        console.log(data);
        var width = 960,
            height = 500,
            radius = 6;

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .gravity(.05)
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(80)
            .size([width, height]);

        var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
        var color = d3.scale.category20();

        force
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .links(data.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(data.links);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(data.nodes);

        node.exit().remove();
        link.exit().remove();

        link.enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
                if ("value" in d) {
                    return Math.sqrt(d.value);
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            });

        var groups = node.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node");

        groups.append("circle").attr("r", function (d) {
            if ("id" in d) { return 5; }
            else { return 0; }
        })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.value); })
            .call(force.drag);

        groups.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text("hi");

        node.selectAll("text")
            .text(function (d) {
                if ("label" in d) {
                    return d.label;
                } else {
                    return d.id;
                }
            }
            );

        force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            node.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
            node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I simply cannot fathom where does the weight even come from.

Comment: The weight from:   `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8X19.png

Comment: It's a JavaScript error message being thrown by the library you are using. You should check their documentation/support material for further help.